# Ошибка в логическом индексировании в matlab

Tags: алгоритм, matlab

Здравствуйте, я относительно недавно задавал вопрос касательно этой задачи, но никто к сожалению вопроса правильно не понял. В общем,условие звучит так:
Задан произвольный массив, написать программу, которая создает сокращенный массив, в котором элементы из заданного массива, удаляются по условию `x(j)<=x(j-n)`, если `j-n>0` или `x(j)<=x(N-n+j)`, если `j-n<=0`. Где N кол-во элементов заданного массива, а n кол-во элементов сокращенного массива. Проблема в том, что такое задание надо сделать без использования циклов, надо использовать только функции массивов/матриц. Например, с N=6 x=[1 6 5 -7 3 2], при n=3 получаем массив, удовлетворяющий условию: y=[1 6 5]. Я воспользовался методом логического индексирования, но все равно получаю неверный ответ при решении, может кто-нибудь подсказать где я напортачил? 
Сам код:

```
N = 6;
n = 3;
x = randi([-100 100],1, N)
%x = [1 6 5 -7 3 2];
J = 1:N;
y =x(find(x(x(J)<=x(mod(J-n, size(x,2))+1))& x(x(J)<=x(mod(N-n+J, size(x,2))+1))));
z =y(1:3)
```